# How to Validation that User should enter any of two field

Tags: javascript, validation

form html

```
<form action="" method="post" name="add_new_report" id="add_new_report" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return AddNewReport(this)">
   <div class="field">
              <div class="field_180">Cheque</div>
              <div class="field_30">:</div>
              <div class="field_220">
                <input type="text" name="cheque" id="cheque" onChange="updatesum()" />
              </div>
              <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
              <div class="field_180">Cash</div>
              <div class="field_30">:</div>
              <div class="field_220">
                <input type="text" name="cash" id="cash" onChange="updatesum()" />
              </div>
              <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>

<div class="field">
              <div class="field_210">&nbsp;</div>
              <div class="field_222">
                <input type="submit" id="Submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"  />
              </div>
              <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
          </form>
```

in this form user should enter either cheque or cash Field how is it possible ? i don't want to be both are mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely do not care about IE <9 you could use something like the following. (otherwise replace the code not working in IE, with some that does)

```
function oneShouldHaveData(ids) {
    var elements = [];

    //convert ids to elements (map no IE<9)
    elements = ids.map(function (id) {
        return document.querySelector('#' + id);
    });

    //returns true if any element matches expression (some no IE <9)
    return elements.some(function (element) {
        //could be validation for anything (greater 0 etc.)  
        return !!element.value;
    });
}

//just submit setup :)
document.querySelector('#add_new_report').addEventListener('submit', function () {
    console.log(oneShouldHaveData(['cheque', 'cash']));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LXprX/1/

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this function to your header:

```
<script>
    function validateForm()
    {
    var x=document.forms["add_new_report"]["cheque"].value;
    var y=document.forms["add_new_report"]["cash"].value;
    if ((x==null || x=="") && (y==null || y==""))
      {
      alert("At least one entry should be filled");
      return false;
      }
     else 
      return true
     }
</script>
```

and change the following field:

```
 onsubmit="if(validateForm()) return AddNewReport(this)"
```

You can also include AddNewReport in validateForm function and only return validate(this) function.